# TypeError: props.price.toFixed is not a function

Tags: reactjs

so I have this function:

```
const buildControls = (props) => (
  <div className="BuildControls">
    <p>
      Trenutna cena: <strong>{props.price.toFixed(2)}</strong>
    </p>
    {controls.map((ctrl) => (
      <BuildControl
        key={ctrl.label}
        label={ctrl.label}
        added={() => props.ingredientAdded(ctrl.type)}
        removed={() => props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)}
        disabled={props.disabled[ctrl.type]}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
  
);
```

And I keep getting this error:

[image: Error that's been occuring]

And I have no clue how it's not working. Props.price IS a number, it's not an issue

Comment: Error is informing you that during *some* render that `props.price` is a value that doesn't have a `toFixed` function to call. Are you sure it's ***always*** a number? Can you update your question to include a more comprehensive code example so we can see the origin of the `price` value and anything that ever updates it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, it's always a number. It's declared as a number, i just wanted to shorten the decimal part to 2

Comment: Try to use optional chaining like this: `props.price?.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @Holunderyogele That would be from a different error, if `props.price` was null or undefined ("cannot access X of undefined"), not a defined object without a `toFixed` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your number is a string.

Try this:

```
parseFloat(props.price).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: I tried that, and then I get NaN as my number

Comment: Does your price include currency symbol as well? Can you console.log and see the price?

Comment: Where do i use that console.log? I cant use it, it's react app, and it won't allow me to do it inside the function

Comment: You, my friend, are a legend. My price contained a currency symbol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check the type of the props.price using console.log(typeOf(props.price)).

Comment: Where do i use that? I cant use it, it's react app, and it won't allow me to do it inside the function